# Simulate telnet communication on one machine

Tags: linux, telnet, iptables

I need to practice iptables on linux, therefore i got a question that ask me to open 2 VMs (A and B), and create rule for preventing A doing telnet to machine B. i need to screenshot the wireshark to prove it.

is there a way to do this task from my ubuntu without using another vm?
maybe to open 2 telnet session on localhost or something?

Thank you,
Asaf

Answer (score 1):

Yes, iptables can work on localhost also.

```
iptables -A INPUT -i lo ...
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo ...
```

Comment: Yeah but how do i simulate a telnet communication ? i need to show somehow that a telnet between A and B has been prevented

Comment: `telnet localhost 22`